# No definition registered for type: project_save.NewDashboardAccessors, arguments: (), tag: nil

Tags: ios, swift, viper-architecture, viper

I am new to Swift IOS native development and working on an Old Project for the same.

The project structure is following VIPER Design pattern. I am getting runtime error during an API call.

I am getting below runtime error:

> No definition registered for type:
> project_save.NewDashboardAccessors, arguments: (), tag: nil.
> Check the tag, type you try to resolve, number, order and types of
> runtime arguments passed to `resolve()` and match them with registered
> factories for type project_stage.NewDashboardAccessors. 2024-02-12
> 13:58:24.288 [Error] [main] [NewDashboardFactory.swift:25]
> viewController(navigation:) > Dependency could not be resolved in
> project_save.NewDashboardFactoryImplementation class

My Accessors class is as below:

```
import Foundation
import Alamofire

protocol NewDashboardAccessors {
    func getDashboardTableData(handler:@escaping (Result<DashboardTableDataModel>) -> Void)
}

protocol NewDashboardAccessorsAPIResourceProvider {
    func getDashboardTableData() -> EndpointAppAPI
}

class NewDashboardAccessorsImplementation: NewDashboardAccessors {
    // MARK: -  Private Properties
    fileprivate let webService: WebService
    fileprivate let apiResourceProvider: NewDashboardAccessorsAPIResourceProvider

    fileprivate var user: User?
    
    // MARK: - Initialization / Deinitialization
    init(webService: WebService, apiResourceProvider: NewDashboardAccessorsAPIResourceProvider) {
        self.webService = webService
        self.apiResourceProvider = apiResourceProvider
    }

    func getDashboardTableData(handler:@escaping (Result<DashboardTableDataModel>) -> Void) {
        webService.load(apiResourceProvider.getDashboardTableData(), completion: handler)
    }
}
```

I have done below code in Presenter class:

```
func callDashboardTableApi() {
    self.view?.state = .loading
    //appSpeedAnalytics.startTrackingTime(feature: .summary)
    self.handleReachability {[weak self] in
        self?.view?.state = .retry(closure: {_ in
            self?.view?.state = .idle
            self?.callDashboardTableApi()
        })
    }
    
    interactor.getDashboardTableData() {[weak self] (result) in
        switch result {
        case .success(let info):
              self?.view?.state = .idle
              if let error = info.hasError {
                  self?.handleError(hasError: error, info: info.msg, handler: nil)
              } else {
                  self?.appSpeedAnalytics.stopTrackingTime(label: .success)
              }
        case .failure(let error):
            log.error("error..\(error.localizedDescription)")
            self?.appSpeedAnalytics.stopTrackingTime(label: .fail)
            self?.view?.state = .retry(closure: {_ in
                self?.view?.state = .idle
                self?.callDashboardTableApi()
            })
        }
    }
}
```

Below is the factory class:

```
import UIKit
import Dip

protocol NewDashboardFactory {
    func viewController(navigation: UINavigationController) -> UIViewController
}

class NewDashboardFactoryImplementation: NewDashboardFactory {

    func viewController(navigation: UINavigationController) -> UIViewController {
        var appearanceProvider: NewDashboardAppearanceProvider?
        var dashAccessors: NewDashboardAccessors?
        do {
            appearanceProvider = try DependencyContainer.shared.resolve() as NewDashboardAppearanceProvider
            dashAccessors = try DependencyContainer.shared.resolve() as NewDashboardAccessors
        } catch {
            log.error(dependencyResolveError(factory: "\(self)"))
        }

        let view = NewDashboardViewController(appearance: appearanceProvider?.newDashboardAppearance)
        let interactor = NewDashboardInteractorImplementation(dashboardAccessors: dashAccessors)
        let wireframe  = NewDashboardWireframeImplementation()
        let presenter  = NewDashboardPresenterImplementation(view: view, interactor: interactor, wireframe: wireframe)
        interactor.output = presenter
        view.output       = presenter
        return view
    }
}
```

I have compared it with other implemented modules but could not got the exact idea why this is happening. Something is with Accessors class.

What might be the issue? Let me know If you want more code to check.

Comment: Is there anyone who can answer this ?

Answer (score 0):

This sounds like a problem with dependency resolution when trying to resolve instances of NewDashboardAccessors in your NewDashboardFactoryImplementation class. Can you confirm you have those validations below?

```
// 1. Confirm proper registration of NewDashboardAccessors in the Dependency Container.
DependencyContainer.shared.register { NewDashboardAccessorsImplementation(webService: $0, apiResourceProvider: $1) as NewDashboardAccessors }

// 2. Check for correct usage of tags or names in the Dependency Container setup.
let dashAccessors = try DependencyContainer.shared.resolve() as NewDashboardAccessors

// 3. Verify that all dependencies of NewDashboardAccessorsImplementation are registered.
DependencyContainer.shared.register { WebService() }
DependencyContainer.shared.register { SomeAPIResourceProvider() }
```

Ensure there are no circular dependencies in the dependency graph.

Double-check for typos and protocol conformance like `NewDashboardAccessorsImplementation` conforms to `NewDashboardAccessorsAPIResourceProvider` if required.